# Listening for onActivityResault in View.OnCLickListener

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent

So the problem is the following:

I'm generating a `contentView` in code with multiple `for` and `foreach` loops and have all of the listeners for buttons generated dynamically. But if I want to make changes in some `TextView` or something, I start a new Activity, and I want to listen for on `onActivityResult` inside a listener.
I'm wondering if that's even possible and I could really use some help.

Here's my code:

```
    Button goliButton = new Button(this);
        goliButton.setText("+");
        goliButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(TekmaLive.this,DodajStrel.class);
                i.putExtra("MINUTA", currTime /1000 + cetrtina * 15 * 60);
                i.putExtra("TEKMA", tekmaId);
                i.putExtra("IGRALKA", Integer.parseInt(igralka[0]));
                i.putExtra("GOL", true);
                TekmaLive.this.startActivity(i);
                //Insted of startActivity I would use startActivityForResult...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the method "wait" for the activity to return its result, if that's why you're asking, startActivity() is asynchronous. However, you can achieve the same by "remembering" which button fired the event, i.e. by having a variable (pressedButton) in your activity referencing it.

```
    final Button goliButton = new Button(this);  // <---
    goliButton.setText("+");
    goliButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TekmaLive.this,DodajStrel.class);
            i.putExtra("MINUTA", currTime /1000 + cetrtina * 15 * 60);
            i.putExtra("TEKMA", tekmaId);
            i.putExtra("IGRALKA", Integer.parseInt(igralka[0]));
            i.putExtra("GOL", true);
            TekmaLive.this.pressedButton = goliButton;  // <---
            TekmaLive.this.startActivityForResult(i, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);  // <---
        }
    });
```

then just read pressedButton in onActivityResult().

Also, you should use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of startActivity() so that onActivityResult() is called afterwards.

Comment: Ok, you slightly missed the point, my code for generating looks like this: 
        for(...){
        //Read from database
        TextView foo= new TextView(this);...
        row.addView(foo);
        }
so I can't access it directly.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I updated it with the changes I believe you should make.

Comment: Ok, but how could I access that TextView which vas Declarated within the for loop??

Comment: Just have the OnClickListener set it when it's fired. The example does it for the button, but you can use any other control declared in the same scope (be sure to mark it as final).

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your code you are using `startActivity`. You should use `startActivityForResult` if you want a result back.

`onActivityResult` is a method that belongs to an `Activity` or a `Fragment`. If you call  `startActivityForResult` from an `Activity` the corresponding `onActivityResult` of that activity instance will be called, when your child activity calls the `finish` method.

What you can do in your case is to have your activity implement `View.OnClickListener`. This way your result will return in the listener.